# How can I unblacklist 'libnvomx.so', in order to resolve "no such element factory 'omxh264enc'!"?

Tags: docker, dependencies, gstreamer, nvidia, shared-objects

(Background: In a docker container on a NVidia Jetson TX2 board I have decompressed NVidia's Linux For Tegra tarball which contains lots of drivers and shared object files, some of which provide GStreamer element factories which produce elements that I use in my GStreamer pipeline. I am trying to run the pipeline in the docker container.)

However, there is an element in my GStreamer pipeline (on this Tegra board), called 'omxh264enc', which I haven't been able to create.

I've put the corresponding 'libnvomx.so' in my drivers folder which is in the exported paths GST_PLUGIN_PATH and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

ldd -r does not show any missing libraries for libnvomx.so

HOWEVER when I try and run the pipeline, output includes

```
WARN   omx gstomx.c:2826:plugin_init: Failed to load configuration file: Valid key file could not be found in search dirs (searched in: /root/.config:/etc/xdg as per GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR environment variable, the xdg user config directory (or XDG_CONFIG_HOME) and the system config directory (or XDG_CONFIG_DIRS)
INFO   omx gstomx.c:2831:plugin_init: Using default configuration
ERROR   omx gstomx.c:2894:plugin_init: Core '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvomx.so' does not exist for element 'omxh264enc'
WARN   GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:526:gst_plugin_register_func: plugin "/gst_1.8.3/libs/gstreamer-1.0/libnvomx.so" failed to initialise
```

and when I use GST_DEBUG=3 gst-inspect-1.0 libnvomx.so, libnvomx.so is blacklisted.

```
Plugin Details:
Name                     libnvomx.so
Description              Plugin for blacklisted file
Filename                 /gst_1.8.3/libs/gstreamer-1.0/libnvomx.so
Version                  0.0.0
License                  BLACKLIST
Source module            BLACKLIST
Binary package           BLACKLIST
Origin URL               BLACKLIST
```

I have copied libnvomx.so into /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra but this did not make a difference (probably because libnvomx is blacklisted).

I don't know where to find the gstomx.conf file, where maybe I can change the path /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvomx.so to my designated drivers folder (/gst_1.8.3/libs/gstreamer-1.0/). I have used 'find' on /etc and some other folders but didn't find it (I didn't actually find a .config folder on the system).

(There are also other plugins with missing symbols, nvidia_drv.so with undefined symbol TimerSet and libglx.so with undefined symbol serverClient. I would like to find out what is suppose to provide these symbols? But these are not (direct) dependencies of libnvomx.so)

So how can I initialise / unblacklist libnvomx.so so I can use 'omxh264enc'? Do I need to find / make a gstomx configuration file or can I make it work with the default configuration? I read somewhere there may be a solution using a 'symlink' but at the moment I'm not familiar with what these are or how these work.

Let me know if you need more info, thanks.